# Why does ls -x not produce one entry per line per the man page documentation?

Tags: linux, ls

I am trying to feed the results of ls into a Perl script. The man page for ls indicates that using the -x switch, ls should output one entry per line. However, it would seem that ls and ls -x produce exactly the same output. Now if I do ls -1, I get the desired output. So, what does the -x switch actually do?

Comment: I see many options inside `man ls`: `-x     list entries by lines instead of by columns` and `--format=WORD ---> across -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column -1, verbose -l, vertical -C` But then they not seem to be working. This is the one that may be useful for you --> `ls --format 'single-column'`, although the obvious is to use `ls -1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you read that `-x` lists one file per line, but that is wrong. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) says `-x` lists files by lines instead of by columns (i.e. two consecutive files will be displayed in two consecutive lines instead of two consecutive columns).

The option you're looking for is `-1`.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer at first, but now that I do, you get the checkmark. If whoever wrote that man page used the word `sorts` or `orders` instead of `lists`, I think it would be *far* more clear.

Answer (score 2):

It's display in line not one entry per line

```
ls display
aaaaaaaaa ccccccccc eeeeeeeeee ggggggggg
bbbbbbbbb ddddddddd ffffffffff hhhhhhhhh

ls - x display
aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd
eeeeeeeee ffffffffff ggggggggg hhhhhhhhh
```

Comment: +1 to you sir! I think you've just solved the mystery of -x and demonstrated with an obvious example. It sorts within the columns of a line of output, before moving to the next line. The default is to sort by column (i.e., fill first column with sorted items, then move to next column).

Answer (score 1):

According to : `man ls`

```
   *    List entries in multiple columns by specifying either the -C or -x flag. The -C flag is the default format when output is to a tty. The ls command displays single
        column output if file or directory names are too long.
```

so in fact, -x is another way of saying -C, which tells ls to output several files per columns.

You probably want:

```
ls -1
```

But if you are trying to feed a list of files to another command, do NOT use ls.

have a look at : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (item #1, but read also the whole thing, very informative)

Comment: OK, so -x and -C are the same. I don't have the text you quoted from the man page in my man page for ls.

Comment: Thanks for the BashPitfalls link, that was very informative and a +1 for going beyond just answering the question.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: another OS ^^ . I couldn't quote from yours. But usually a "man ls" will turn out what you want to know. Albeit sometime a bit criptically... (the manual pages for "find" are a good example, as some of the quirks of its use are not easily guessed from even multiple readings of it)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: you're welcome. I love that site. Read also their http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide pages when you have some time (your question is definitely not a XYProblem. Still it's good to read it, and refer people to it when they do ask a XYProblem question ^^).